# Is Kurt Vonnegut’s Slaughterhouse Five an allegory of what would now be called PTSD?

Tags: terminology, allegory, kurt-vonnegut, slaughterhouse-five

Is Kurt Vonnegut’s Slaughterhouse Five an allegory of what would now be called PTSD? Would ‘allegory’ be the correct terminology here?